# stylus: --watch automatically recompile the wrong file

Tags: stylus

I have, let's say, two stylus file including the some `common.styl`, like below:

```
- css/
- stylus/
   | - homepage.styl
   | - article.styl
   | - lib/
        | - common.styl
```

`homepage.styl`:

```
@import "lib/common.styl
// blah blah blah
```

`article.styl`:

```
@import "lib/common.styl
//blah blah blah
```

When I setup the `stylus -w stylus/ -o css/` and as I modify the `common.styl` file, the stylus re-compiled the `article.style` only, the `homepage.styl` has been ignored.

Do you guys have any idea about this?

Comment: I believe it just watches one file relation and as you have one file with two relation it just takes the one iterated over last. To remedy this you probably have to just save your homepage.styl yourself by hand. :(

Comment: This is something that can easily be accomplished with a task manager like Gulp.js or Grunt.js. Both are totally worth investing time in learning.